# Not able to select suggestions by clicking (only tab works) react-places-autocomplete. (not z-index issue)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, autocomplete, redux-form

I'm trying to change display value of an input field after clicking on a suggestion from react-places-autocomplete. Clicking on a suggestion hides drop-down with suggestions, the selected value is not saved nor displayed.

I assumed that using the following code should solve the issue:

```
.then(() => {
                this.props.change("venue", selectedVenue)
            })
```

But it doesn't work. Below the whole snippet.

```
handleVenueSelect = selectedVenue => {
        geocodeByAddress(selectedVenue)
            .then(results => getLatLng(results[0]))
            .then(latlng => {
                this.setState({
                    venueLatLng: latlng
                });
            })
            .then(() => {
                this.props.change("venue", selectedVenue)
            })
            .catch(error => console.log('geocode ERROR'))
    }
```

```
<Field
                                            name='venue'
                                            type='text'
                                            component={PlaceInput}
                                            options={{
                                                location: new google.maps.LatLng(this.state.cityLatLng),
                                                radius: 1000,       
                                                types: ['establishment'] 
                                                }}
                                            placeholder='Event Venue'
                                            onSelect={this.handleVenueSelect}
                                            />
```

Currently, I can make this work only after clicking on a tab button, but can't achieve that by clicking directly on the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example demonstrates how to handle the selected suggestion and pass it into `Field` component via [Input object](https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/docs/api/field.md/#usage):

```
const LocationSearchInput = props => {
  const handleChange = address => {
    props.input.onChange({ name: address });
  };

  const handleSelect = address => {
    geocodeByAddress(address)
      .then(results => getLatLng(results[0]))
      .then(latLng => {
        props.input.onChange({ name: address, location: latLng });
      })
      .catch(error => console.error("Error", error));
  };

  const SuggestionsList = ({
    getInputProps,
    getSuggestionItemProps,
    suggestions,
    loading
  }) => (
    <div className="autocomplete-root">
      <input {...getInputProps()} />
      <div className="autocomplete-dropdown-container">
        {loading && <div>Loading...</div>}
        {suggestions.map(suggestion => (
          <div {...getSuggestionItemProps(suggestion)}>
            <span>{suggestion.description}</span>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );

  const {
    input: { value }
  } = props;

  return (
    <PlacesAutocomplete
      onChange={handleChange}
      onSelect={handleSelect}
      value={value ? value.name : ""}
    >
      {SuggestionsList}
    </PlacesAutocomplete>
  );
}
```

Here is a [**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7wuxzm) for your reference

Comment: by selecting arrow button it's working fine, not filling input box while selecting by mouse click

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution for this is, you can set the onClick in the div which shows suggestionItemProps. **Check out line 10**

```
<PlacesAutoComplete value={this.state.address} onChange={this.handleChange} onSelect={this.handleSelect} defaultValue={this.state.address} >
    {({ getInputProps, suggestions, getSuggestionItemProps, loading}) => (
        <div>
            <input className="partner-info-input" {...getInputProps({placeholder: "Address"})} />
            <div>
                {loading ? <div>Loading...</div> : null}
                {suggestions.map(suggestion => {
                    const style = suggestion.active ? { backgroundColor: '#974803', cursor: 'pointer' } : { backgroundColor: '#2d2d2d', cursor: 'pointer' };
                    return(
                        <div {...getSuggestionItemProps(suggestions, { style })} onClick={(e) => {this.handleClick(suggestion)}}>
                            {suggestion.description}
                        </div>
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    )}
</PlacesAutoComplete>
```

In handleClick method

```
handleClick(address) {
    geocodeByAddress(address.description)
        .then(results => getLatLng(results[0]))
        .then(latLng => this.setState({address: address.description, lat: latLng.lat, long: latLng.lng}))
        .catch(error => console.error('Error', error));
}
```